# getLayoutInflater() in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to show my results search in a `ListView` on the `Fragment`, but it fails on:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

> The method getLayoutInflater(Bundle) in the type Fragment is not
>   applicable for the arguments ()

This is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   View row;

   row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);

   TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
   ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row
     .findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

   textview.setText(data_text[position]);
   imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

   return (row);

  }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());`

Answer (score 165):

if you are in a fragment you want

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

or

```
LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
```

also you can do

```
View.inflate();
```

or

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: i try this 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

but error, 
"context cannot be resolved"

Comment: i don't understand
i don't have context variabel

Comment: then create one in your main activity

Comment: use getActivity() instead of context

Comment: my fault , i was pasting a layout name from other context instead of the real one in the context, that is why i was getting null pointer exception on layout inflate

Answer (score 7):

In Activity you can use like this:

```
this.getLayoutInflater();
```

For Fragment you need to replace keyword "this" with "getActivity()"

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 4):

Now and don't know from when you can get it in your Fragment(support library v4) by

```
getLayoutInflater(null);
```

Comment: Passing null u are losing theme values

Comment: @busylee The parameter is a nullable Bundle - savedFragmentState. I don't understand where the connection to "theme values" could be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inflate layout (attach child layout to parent) in `Fragment`

Use this code

`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Now to `Inflate` child layout

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_child, null);
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use it:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: can add please add more information above the question