# android onCreateView efficiency

Tags: java, android

In my application I have only one activity `MainActivity`, in it's `activity_main.xml` I have `<FrameLayout>` tag which I use to change the content of screen using `Frame` in a way like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.id_of_FrameLayout, myFrameInstance)
        .commit();
```

Can I initialize some fields (like `Buttons`s, `TextView`s, `ButtonListener`s) in this `Frame` before calling `onCreateView`? For now I initilize all of them each time in `onCreateView` because only in this place I have `LayoutInflater` using which I inflate `frame_this_screen.xml` but it seems to me not really effectient.

So I want to write some `setUp()` method in my `Frame` class and pass something like `LayoutInflater` from `MainActivity` to it to initilize all my fields in this place and in `onCreateView` only make some small changes with this fields. How can I pass such `LayoutInflater` to my `setUp` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can only initialize your content in the onCreateView() may be just create a method you can call and pass in the parameters of inflater and viewGroup to initialize your content and call it from your onCreateView() method like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  setUp(inflater,container);
     /*rest of the method*/
   }
```

Also

```
    private void setUp(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent){
               /*Set up your content here*/
     }
```

Comment: but that doesn't solves the problem. I still will be itiliziating all the fields every time `onCreateView` called or in `setUp` I have to check every time that the object is not `null` and only initilize if it's `null` but my code will become a total mess then.

Comment: The problem is that if you try to initialize it before `onCreateView()` method,Your app may crash due to a null reference to the inflater and viewGroup

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to LayoutInflater from a context like this (check if it is != null) or pick [another variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26368236/3522053).

```
(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
```

Also make sure that you are not spending much time on premature optimization - do some measurements to see if there really is a problem with `onCreateView()`.