# Creating PopupView from button in ListView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I'm trying to implement popup view into my app with bottom navigation (I'm using fragments for every item in navigation). In one fragment I have `ListView` with items. Each Item has button in it and I want to create popup view that tells further info about its item.

I have tried creating popups in separate apps on activities and it worked just fine, therefore I assume this is problem of slightly complicated structure of my app. (Activity - fragment - listView - Item - button that summons popup)

Here is my code:

Fragment:

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment implements myListAdapter.EventListener {

...

@Override
public void setPopupLayout() {

    Log.d(TAG, "setPopupLayout");

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_compressors, null);

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 500, 500, true);

    TextView textView = popupView.findViewById(R.id.popup_details);
    textView.setText("xd");

    // Here the error seems to occur
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY ,400, 400);
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Compressor>
{
private static final String TAG = "Compressor Adapter";

EventListener myListener;

// (...)

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

// (...)  

    Button button = convertView.findViewById(R.id.comp_details);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: button");
            myListener.setPopupLayout();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

When I click the button in listView, app prints both `Log.d(TAG, "onClick: button");` and `Log.d(TAG, "setPopupLayout");`.
Then `NullPointerExeption` is thrown:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference`

and this line gets highlited:

`popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY ,400, 400);`

I'm still new to android and I will be so thankful for any piece of advice! Thanks for reading

**EDIT:**

I think I found the issue, in

`popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY ,400, 400);`

I use `popupLayout` which is assigned in `onViewCreated` as

`popupLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative);`

and this is assigned as null (which seems to be causing the error).

Comment: From your `Fragment` where you setup your list adapter, get the `LayoutInflator` first and pass it into your list adapter and store it as a `local variable`. Then where you inflate your popup, use the local layoutinflator passed from the fragment activity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26368236/1876355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY ,400, 400);`

by `popupWindow.showAtLocation(getView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY ,400, 400);`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Fragment.class

```
View popupView =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_compressors, null);
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 500, 500);

popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY ,400, 400);
```

Comment: @DeepBlue what is your error in Logcat, this non null reference ?

Comment: the error is still the same unfortunately  
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object reference

Comment: I will try to make a code for this and show if it works